# Document-based Core-Data drawing application under OS-X

Tags: cocoa, design-patterns, core-data, drawing, osx-lion

I'm developing a document-based drawing application under OS-X 10.7 and I'm unsure about some code design decisions.

To store the graphic elements I want to use Core Data, due to the fact that undo, etc. is very simple. Is there something to say against that? I also want to use KVC & KVO where possible and recommended.

If I took this right the ManagedObjectContext lays in the Document. The graphics (and children of Graphic objects) are stored in this MOC. This objects have to be drawn by the view.

Now how would to pass the reference to the managedObjects to the view? Would you create a NSArrayController and pass it to the view programmatically or via the interface builder? Or would you pass the reference to the MOC to the view and then iterate over the managedObjects in it every time it has to draw? How should the view observe the changes of the managedObjects it has to draw? Btw. I don't get the idea behind the NSArrayController completely: may you help me here?

If the user selects a tool and clicks into the view, a new graphic (managedObject) has to be created. Where would you put the code to create a new graphic? Into the view, or should the view message the document and the creation is done there?

Thanks for your help!